# Changing assertions in SOAP UI for different server

Tags: soapui

I have my tests prepared for one servers, each test case has its own assertion like this:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://test.server.001';
//ns1:Response[1]/ns1:errorCode[1]/text()
expected: 1
```

It perfectly fine when I'm working with this test.server.001. Now I need to run my tests of test.server.002, but I'm getting Assertion Failed because of different namespace.

Is there a quick way to changes assertions for all my cases, I don't want to change those manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the assertion tied to each request (as opposed to storing the assertion in a variable), there isn't a quick way to change them all.

The fastest way I have found is to open the XML file in a text editor and do a find/replace all.

Comment: to future proof your script, I would make namespace a variable in your assertion.

Comment: even better, you can set the namespace as a property called `ns`, and reference it like so in your assertions: `${ns}`